# How to handle null check throughout project in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

BE API is returing data like :

```
{
  "details": {
    "address": {
      "street": "123/4",
      "city": "Banglore"
    }
  }
}
```

in our react project we are consumming it like details.address.street at multiple place.

this is one of example but there are multile other objects where we hanvent taken care of null checks.

now since we are tring to change BE API object it will start breaking .

also going to each file of code and handling null checks specifically is a bigger task.

i want some suggestion on how can we hadle this in generic and efficient way.

Comment: find and replace to add `details?.address?.street` or where ever you fetch this JSON you can add in default for the missing properties.

Comment: Erm...you can't. You're asking for magic. You either bite the bullet and try to be thorough or just don't and let things break. Note: even TS won't help here, since you likely do not have enough information in your project for it to deduce the types you have and which is nullable or not. Although, if you do decide to bite the bullet, you can ease your work by introducing TS + proper types and let the compiler yell at you. But that doesn't sound like what you're asking for.

Comment: If you are still early in the project, it might be beneficial to switch to typescript. With typecheck and a good IDE, you can easily handle potential null checks

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator for the checks and the [Nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) operator for a default value if some value in the chain is `null` or `undefined`:

```
response.details?.address?.street ?? 'some default value'
```